# Java - Reading A Double From A Text File

Tags: java, string, double, java.util.scanner

I am trying to read through a file and determine how many numbers (separated by spaces) there are in the line.  If there is one number then that number is set as the radius of a circle and a circle object of that radius is created.  Similar actions are taken with two values (a rectangle) and three values (a triangle).

I believe that the error I am getting is occurring because of a problem with my code that takes numbers from the text file, which are strings, and converts them to doubles using `valueOf` on line 27 of my driver class.

**The issue that I am having is when I run my driver program I get the following error:**

```
Exception in thread "main" java.lang.NumberFormatException: For input string: "in7.txt"
    at sun.misc.FloatingDecimal.readJavaFormatString(FloatingDecimal.java:2043)
    at sun.misc.FloatingDecimal.parseDouble(FloatingDecimal.java:110)
    at java.lang.Double.parseDouble(Double.java:538)
    at java.lang.Double.valueOf(Double.java:502)
    at Assignment7.main(Assignment7.java:27)
```

**Here is my driver class:**

```
import java.util.*;
import java.io.*;
public class Assignment7
{
   public static void main(String[] theArgs)
   {
      String filename = "in7.txt";
      int shapeNum;
      List<Double> shapeValues = new ArrayList<Double>();
      Shape myShape;
      double d;
      Scanner s = new Scanner(filename);
      try 
      {
         if (!s.hasNextLine())
         {
            throw new FileNotFoundException("No file was found!");
         }
         else
         {
            while (s.hasNextLine())
            {
               shapeNum = 0;
               Scanner s2 = new Scanner(s.nextLine());
               while (s2.hasNext())
               {
                  d = Double.valueOf(s2.next());
                  shapeNum++;
                  shapeValues.add(d);
               }
               if (shapeNum == 1)
               {
                  myShape = new Circle(shapeValues.get(0));
               }
               else if (shapeNum == 2)
               {
                  myShape = new Rectangle(shapeValues.get(0), 
                  shapeValues.get(1));
               }
               else
               {
                  myShape = new Triangle(shapeValues.get(0),
                  shapeValues.get(1), shapeValues.get(2));
               }
               shapeValues.clear();
               System.out.println(myShape);
            }
         }
         s.close();
      } 
      catch (FileNotFoundException e) 
      {
         System.out.println("File not found!" + e);
      }
   }
}
```

I've been fiddling with this code for an hour and I cannot get it to run correctly.  Some help would be greatly appreciated.  Thanks!

Comment: new Scanner() doesn't take a filename. You're just processing the filename as a string, not the contents of the file.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

you should pass a file to the scanner .
like this

```
File filename = new File("in7.txt");
Scanner s = new Scanner(filename);
```

currently you are passing a String `in7.txt` and that's why you get error

```
NumberFormatException: For input string: "in7.txt"
```

Comment: I see now, the only problem with that is now I'm getting a new error.  Would you happen to know why I am getting `Assignment7.java:12: error: unreported exception FileNotFoundException; must be caught or declared to be thrown`?

Comment: @Trafton you should handle the filenotfound exception .put try catch block

Comment: it means `Scanner s = new Scanner(filename);` throws a `FileNotFoundException`. You have to `catch` it or `throw` it

Comment: Oh, but I thought I already took care of that with the try/catch I have for the FileNotFoundException.  Are you saying I need another one inside that one?

Comment: @Trafton `Scanner s = new Scanner(filename);` line isn't inside of `try` block so you can move that line in to the try block

Comment: Doh!  I didn't notice that.  Thank you for all the help, I'm getting an output now!